# A problem of mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am stuck by a problem of mathematical induction. The problem is:

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers. Prove that for each positive integer $n$ which is odd, we have $(x + y)$ divides $(x^n + y^n)$.

What I did is as follows:

For $n = 1$, $x^n + y^n = x + y$, which is obviously divisible by $x + y$;

For $n = k$ (odd), assume that $x^k + y^k$ is divisible by $x + y$, namely,
\begin{equation}
x^k + y^k = a(x+y),   \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is an integer;

For $n = k+2$, we have
\begin{equation}
x^{n} + y^{n} = x^{k+2} + y^{k+2}.  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I don't know how to proceed. How to make use of eq. (1) to prove the right-hand side of eq. (2) is divisible by $(x+y)$?

Comment: Do you **have** to prove it by induction?

Comment: Yes, it is required to use mathematical induction to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that:

\begin{align*}
x^{k+2}+ y^{k+2} &= x^2(x^k + y^k - y^k) + y^{k+2} \\
&= x^2(x^k + y^k) + y^k(y^2-x^2)\\
&= x^2(x^k + y^k) + y^k(y-x)(x+y)
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) I was after something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive this directly from

- $x^n -y^n = (x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{n-1-k}y^k$

by noting that $n= 2i+1$ and writing

$$x^{2i+1} + y^{2i+1} = x^{2i+1} - (-y)^{2i+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

In context:

$x^k+y^k=a(x+y).$

$x^{k+2}= a(x+y)x^2-y^kx^2.$

$y^{k+2}=a(x+y)y^2-x^ky^2.$

$x^{k+2}+y^{k+2} = $

$a(x+y)(x^2+y^2)-y^2x^2(y^{k-2}+x^{k-2})$

First summand divisible by $(x+y)$.

Second summand: Divisible by (x+y) (hypothesis?).

Can I invoke the hypothesis for $k-2?$

Comments welcome.

.